# Getting an executable from Python scripts + bash + data files

Tags: python, bash, executable, pyinstaller, py2app

I am trying to get an executable file from Python script (MAC OS). But the thing is I'm not in the simplest case : I have a main Python script calling a bash script, and the bash is calling other python files. Plus those scripts need data files (pickle and csv files). Furthermore, I don't know if it's important but my code is creating other datafiles for using them afterwhat.

Is it even possible to get an executable from that? I tried with py2app and pyInstaller:

- With py2app I think I understood how to pass data files and python scripts to setup.py, but what about the bash? I pu it with the python scripts in the option "py_modules" or with the data files and it's never working
- With pyInstaller I didn't even find how to pass several python scripts, I tried to import them in the main file but it didn't work.

So does someone have an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Marie

Comment: Can you convert your bash file to a python script ?

Comment: I am trying now, instead of calling the bash I'm calling the python scripts, but how can I pass the arguments of the python scripts knowing they are in variables?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I also have a shapefile. And I tried again with using only python files and datafiles (csv, pickle, shapefiles) but it's still not working. With py 2app I get the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded". Any idea?